# How to use Pry with Cucumber / Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, pry

What should I do to use Pry for debuging my Cucumber steps? Here is an example.

```
When 'I download a PDF via "$label"' do |label|
  old_body = page.body
  click_link(label)
  page.driver.instance_variable_set '@body', page.body.pdf_to_text
  binding.pry
end
```

When I run a single scenario with that step I get access to Pry console

```
[1] pry(#<Cucumber::Rails::World>)>
```

but I can't write anything. It seems that it stops working. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you press Ctrl-D?  Does it continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the same thing again after upgrading Rails to 3.2.10 + Capybara to 2.0.2 and now Pry works flawless.